# Why do C# 7.2 features not compile in a UWP application?

Tags: c#, uwp, c#-7.2, in-parameters

... in particular, `in` (`readonly ref`) parameters.  Here's my situation:

I have a UWP project and a UWP Unit Test project in the same Visual Studio solution. Both projects target C# 7.2  The main UWP project has this class (note the `in` parameters):

```
public struct Cell
{
    public Cell(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int X { get; }

    public int Y { get; }

    public static Cell operator +(in Cell left, in Cell right)
    {
        return new Cell(left.X + right.X, left.Y + right.Y);
    }

    public static Cell operator -(in Cell left, in Cell right)
    {
        return new Cell(left.X - right.X, left.Y - right.Y);
    }


    public override string ToString() => $"{X}, {Y}";
}
```

When I use those operators **from the UWP test project**:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Cell cell1 = new Cell(0, 0);
        Cell cell2 = new Cell(1, 1);

        var added = cell1 + cell2 ;
        var minus = cell1 - cell2 ;
    }
```

I get:

```
UnitTest.cs(16,25,16,38): error CS0019: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Cell' and 'Cell'
UnitTest.cs(17,25,17,38): error CS0019: Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Cell' and 'Cell'
```

However, the same usage **inside the main UWP project** does not produce any compiler errors.

Why is that?

Comment: So you have selected C# 7.2 in the _Properties > Build > Advanced Build Settings_ **for the test project** as well?

Comment: @AndrésRobinet: Would the test project really need the higher C# level to run tests against the compiled project?

Comment: @Andrés Robinet, yes, both were targetting C# 7.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a compiler bug with `in` in operators, which gets lost when loading the operator from another project/assembly.

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/23508 (the fix will ship in 15.6 preview 3)

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23689 (another report of this issue)

Comment: Thanks @Julien Couvreur.  I wonder (not a question to you :)), if that means that nobody can ship a C# 7.2 compiled assembly that can be consumed by anyone < C# 7.2...?

Comment: @SteveDunn I'm not sure, but I don't think such scenario is affected.